# create .doc file and put image to it using django

Tags: django

I have already generate .doc file using django like this:

```
    template = loader.get_template('test.html')
    savename = os.path.join(save_dir, 'test.doc') 

    file_handle = open(savename,'w')
    file_handle.write(template.render(Context(dicts))
    file_handle.close()
```

but the image file can not be displayed?! And the image is a relative path, and I have tried replace the image src by `<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,...>`, and it does not work.

How can I put images in the doc file?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the way it works. You can't save an HTML and expect it to be opened as a Word Document.

Comment: Thanks, that will help. I will try something else.